# Filter Sitecore SPEAK UI TreeView

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-speak-ui

I'm building a SPEAK UI page in Sitecore 7.2 and would like to use the TreeView component for selecting items.
(see SPEAK UI components here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/72/speak_component_reference_sc72_a4.pdf)

I would like to only show items with specific template but didn't find such functionality.

Is it possible to filter the TreeView somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Sitecore Queries.

You can create a new `QueryDataSource` in SPEAK renderings, and make your Treeview get the data from this datasource.

Then you can create a query like this:

```
query:/sitecore/content/home//*[@@templatename='Document']
```

This will get the item under "home", that has the template name "Document".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check how this works for me.